# how to make next/prev button works jquery gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery

I am new in jquery and with simple problems like this one I feel like it is not for me, but straight to the point... I made a jquery gallery and I don't know how to grab the .miniatures img src and put it to the #mainImg div box.

https://jsfiddle.net/sytknk46/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.miniatures img').on({
    click: function(){

      var imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
      $('#mainImage').attr('src', imageUrl);
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.next').on('click', function(){
    var currentImg = $('#mainImage');
    var mini = $('.imgStyle').attr('src');



    if(mini.length){
      currentImg.removeAttr('src');
      currentImg.addAttr(mini);
    }


  });
});
```

Comment: not sure if this is what you are after but you can get the current mini by using an attribute selector: `$('.imgStyle[src="' + currentImg.attr('src') + '"]')` and then you can do a `.next()` to get the next one or check the next length to see if you need to reset back to the beggining